# How to include only modifications in child theme?

Tags: child-theme

Is there a way to only include single line / minor changes to a child theme without having to maintain the whole template file?

For example, I have a third-party theme which has a single character HTML typo in index.php - to correct the issue I've copied the whole (600+ line) file to my child theme and edited. This fixes the issue, but means that whenever the theme developer updates the theme I have to manually look for the changes in *their* index.php and update *my* child version.

Comment: Is it translatable? Contact the author?

Comment: Thanks - I've already contacted the author and they've issued several theme updates (bug fixes), but not included this one. But in more general terms, it seems that maintaining template files which are hundreds of lines long is a bit crazy for single line changes.